# Prebuilt function to find character sequence in a string?

Tags: c++, string, find, character, sequence

I'm working on a multithreading project where for one segment of the project I need to find if a given character sequence exists within a string. Im wondering if C++/C have any pre-built functions which can handle this, but am having trouble figuring out the exact 'definition' to search for.

I know about 'strtr' and 'find', the issue is the function needs to be able to find a sequence which is SPLIT across a string.

Given the string 'Hello World', I need a function that returns true if the sequence 'H-W-l' exists. Is there anything prebuilt which can handle this?

Comment: The [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, subsequence searching as such is not part of either the standard C library or the standard C++ library.

However, you can express subsequence searching as either a regular expression or a "glob". Posix mandates both regex and glob matching functions, while the C++ standard library includes regular expressions since C++11. Both of these techniques require modifying the search string:

1. Regular expression: `HWl` ⇒ `H.*W.*l`. [`regexec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) will do a search for the regular expression (unless anchored, which this one is not); in C++, you would want to use [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) rather than `std::regex_match`.
2. Glob: `HWl` ⇒ `*H*W*l*`. Glob matching is always a complete match, although in all the implementations I know of a trailing `*` is optimized. This is available as the [`fnmatch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html) function in the Posix header `fnmatch.h`. For this application, provide `0` for the flags parameter.

If you don't like any of the above, you can use the standard C `strchr` function in a simple loop:

```
bool has_subsequence(const char* haystack, const char* needle) {
  const char* p;
  for (p = haystack; *needle && (p = strchr(p, *needle)); ++needle) {
  }
  return p != NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you're trying to search for `char`s in a given order but aren't necessarily contiguous. If you're in C++, I don't see why you couldn't use the `std::find` function under the `<algorithm>` system header. I would load both into a string and then search as follows:

```
bool has_noncontig_sequence(const std::string& str, const std::string& subStr)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iter;
    iter start = str.begin();

    // loop over substr and save iterator position;
    for (iter i = subStr.begin(); i != subStr.end(); ++i)
        start = std::find(start, str.end(), *i);

    // check position, if at end, then false;
    return start != str.end() ? true : false;
}
```

The `std::find` function will position `start` over the first correct character in `str` if it can find it and then search for the next. If it can't, then `start` will be positioned at the end, indicating failure.